# How can I make a proxy an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a proxy coming in with data I need, and can't drill down to so I want to convert the proxy to an object. The schema is as follows:

```
Proxy
  <target>
    0: Proxy
      <target>
        show_info: true
        name: "new field"
```

I'd like to get it to

```
Object{
  "new field": "string"
      }
```

Comment: It looks like some kind of console output, could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: A proxy already *is* an object. Just access it however you want, like `proxy['new field']`.

Comment: do you use mobx?